# Express With Next Js Auth

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am building my very first web app and I want to go with next js for the frontend and Express for the backend.
I used JWT for authentication.

my question is, can I just make a request from the front end to the back end and get back a true or false for users authentication, or since next js is front end this variable could be manipulated, if so how should I go about this?